# How do I git pull the images that have been uploaded to a Heroku site?

Tags: git, heroku

I have an app built with MongoDB, Angular 2, Express and NodeJS deployed on heroku free version. The app uses multer and ng2-file-upload so the admin user can upload photos and display them in blog posts. The app works correctly. I am able to upload photos and display them. The details of the blog post including photo names are all stored in the DB, but the photos are stored in a folder on the server (uploads folder, see pic below). The problem is whenever I deploy/push to heroku the pictures dont persist, but the blog details do. So the feed has a bunch of broken pictures.

Is there a way i can pull the pictures off of the heroku site and commit them so they dont disappear after i deploy?

File Structure:
[image]

I have my github repo connected to heroku app.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I git pull the images that have been uploaded to a Heroku site?

You don't.

Deploying isn't the only thing that will cause your images to disappear. They will also vanish whenever a Dyno restarts ([at least once per day](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#restarting)) thanks to Heroku's [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem).

The recommended solution is to [use a third-party file hosting service like Amazon S3 for user uploads](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3). Here is a [tutorial for doing so with NodeJS](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-node).

(Note that uploaded images are content, not code. I, like many developers, would argue that they shouldn't be committed to your repository in the first place.)